# Updating only one microservice in Docker Containerized Spring Cloud Application ecosystem

Tags: docker-compose, microservices, spring-cloud, docker-container

I have created a Spring Cloud microservice ecosystem which is made up of a spring cloud eureka server, a spring cloud gateway proxy and several microservices. I have also used docker to containerize each of this services and i start up the images using a docker-compose file.

```
version: '3'
services:
  discovery-server:
    image: serviceregistry-api-docker:latest
    ports:
      - 8761:8761
    networks:
      - transaction-network
  api-gateway:
    image: apigateway-api-docker:latest
    environment:
     - JAVA_OPTS=
      -DEUREKA_SERVER=http://discovery-server:8761/eureka/
    depends_on:
      - discovery-server
    ports:
      - 9091:9091
    networks:
      - transaction-network
  utility-service:
    image:  utility-api-docker:latest
    environment:
      - JAVA_OPTS=
       -DEUREKA_SERVER=http://discovery-server:8761/eureka/
    restart: on-failure
    depends_on:
      - discovery-server
      - api-gateway
    ports:
      - 8090:8090
    networks:
      - transaction-network
  banktransfer-service:
    image:  banktransfer-api-docker:latest
    environment:
      - JAVA_OPTS=
        -DEUREKA_SERVER=http://discovery-server:8761/eureka/
    restart: on-failure
    depends_on:
      - discovery-server
      - api-gateway
    ports:
      - 8091:8091
    networks:
      - transaction-network
  ussd-service:
    image:  ussd-api-docker:latest
    environment:
      - JAVA_OPTS=
        -DEUREKA_SERVER=http://discovery-server:8761/eureka/
    restart: on-failure
    depends_on:
      - discovery-server
      - api-gateway
    ports:
      - 8096:8096
    networks:
      - transaction-network
networks:
    transaction-network:
        driver: bridge
```

When i make an update to just 1 microservice and create a new docker image that has my update, how do i replace it with the current running version in the ecosystem ?

Answer (score 0):

Just start it with `--no-deps` [param](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/up/) (even if it already started). For example:

```sh
docker-compose up -d --no-deps api-gateway
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this command to make it possible

```
$docker-compose up -d --no-deps --build <service_name>
```